# Access datasheet form SetFocus to a specified record by ID when the form loads

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I'm having huge issues making a particular datasheet record take the focus when the form is opened, without user intervention.

I have a procedure as follows:

```
Public Sub GoToID(ID As Integer, Optional fldName As String)
On Error Resume Next
    With Me.RecordsetClone
        .FindFirst "ID = " & ID
        If Not .NoMatch Then Me.Bookmark = .Bookmark
    End With
    Dim ctl As Control: Set ctl = Me.Controls(fldName)
    If Not ctl Is Nothing Then ctl.SetFocus
End Sub
```

When I have this on a button_click, or called from a procedure on another form when the target form is already opened, it all works brilliantly.

I want to have something like:

```
Private Sub Form_Activate()
    Me.GoToID User.RecordIdFromLastSession, "Title"
End Sub
```

The behavior I'm getting is, that the line of execution passes through the GotoID procedure error free, but the loaded datasheet form always has the top-most record selected, and the left-most tab-stoppable field selected, where I'd be expecting the recordselector to have moved to User.RecordIdFromLastSession's "Title" field.

If I put the function call into the form's DblClick event, for example, and double click the form header, the function works perfectly, but I cannot do this as I update User.RecordIdFromLastSession dynamically as the user navigates records, using the Form_Current event.

As I can't seem to select the previous session's record before the first Form_Current event fires, the previous session data keeps getting overwritten with whichever record ID is the top-most record at the time the form was opened.

Any help / pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is User a custom class you define? Exactly how does RecordIdFromLastSession get set?

Comment: Yes, User is a custom class held on the "Controller" module. This form is for "Memos", and there is a User.SetActiveMemo property that I set whenever the user navigates to a different memo. It persists this data to a User table, and the recovery of the data between sessions works fine.

Comment: Hmm, I've just done an independent test of this in a new database, with a single table with 5 records. Made a single datasheet form with the same GotoID function, but passed an ID value in the form activate event, and it works fine. 

I have a standard MyRequery procedure which I suspect is being erroneously triggered when the form opens, before I get the chance to recall the last selected record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've sorted this now, but feel I need to put some notes here as there was something in Microsoft's guidance that misguided things.

Microsoft say:

> When you open a form, the following sequence of events occurs for the form:
>
> *Open > Load > Resize > Activate > Current*
>
> When you switch between two open forms, the Deactivate event occurs for the first form, and the Activate event occurs for the second
>   form:
>
> *Deactivate (form1)  > Activate (form2)*

My case is/was that I had one form open already ("Tasks"), and I was opening another form ("Memos") for the first time, and leaving Tasks open.

The above guidance would make you assume the order of events would be:

> *Tasks.Deactivate > Memos.Open > Memos.Load > Memos.Resize > Memos.Activate > Memos.Current*

However, the actual order of events executed when I (eventually) stepped through everything was:

> *Tasks.Deactivate > Memos.Activate > Memos.Current > Memos.Open*

This is / was counterintuitive, after reading MS's guidance. I don't use the Load event in my form, but believe Memos.Load must've occurred before Memos.Open, otherwise Memos.Current wouldn't have been able to fire / identify a record in the recordset.

Anyhow, my desired use-case is now functioning, and I've managed to optimise my coding significantly too along the way, which can only be an added bonus. :)